# PostgreSQL, cформировать вложенный запрос

Tags: sql, postgresql

Подскажите, как сформировать вложенный запрос так, чтобы он брал данные только одного менеджера.

Мне требуется получить список менеджеров (fio) с определённой ролью (oooz) и количество запросов из таблицы requests с определённым статусом (103,104) для каждого из них.
То есть, условно, у одного 10, у второго 5 и т.д.

Проблема в том, что count во вложенном запросе берёт количество всех реквестов без учёта менеджера и у меня не получается их связать. Если на всех менеджеров их 100, то и покажет он 100 в каждой строке, вместо того чтобы вернуть количество у каждого менеджера.

Сокращённый запрос (для удобства понимания)

```
select concat(mn.last_name, ' ', mn.first_name, ' ', mn.middle_name) as fio,
                 (select count(rq.status) from requests rq  where rq.status = '103' or rq.status = '104' ) as assigned
                 from requests rq INNER JOIN managers mn on mn.role = 'oooz' and mn.id = rq.assignee GROUP BY fio;
```

Полный запрос:

```
select concat(mn.last_name, ' ', mn.first_name, ' ', mn.middle_name) as fio,
                (select count(rq.status) from requests rq where rq.status = '103' or rq.status = '104') as assigned,
                (select count(rq.status) from requests rq where rq.status = '401' or rq.status = '501') as routed_to_reg,
                (select count(rq.status) from requests rq where rq.status = '201' or rq.status = '301') as routed_to_esroo,
                (select count(rq.status) from requests rq where rq.status = '112' or rq.status = '212' or rq.status = '213') as closed_by_lifetime,
                (select count(rq.status) from requests rq where rq.status = '110' or rq.status = '111' or rq.status = '207' or rq.status = '211') as closed_after_get_response_to_pet,
                (select count(rq.status) from requests rq where rq.status = '405' or rq.status = '406' or rq.status = '408' 
                       or rq.status = '510' or rq.status = '511' or rq.status = '514')
                from requests rq INNER JOIN managers mn on mn.role = 'oooz' 
                and rq.created_on >= ?1 and rq.created_on <= ?2 and mn.id = rq.assignee GROUP BY fio;
```

Таблицы:

```
create table requests
(
    id bigserial constraint pk_requests primary key,
    assignee bigint constraint fk_assignee references managers,
    status varchar(20) default 'pending processing'::character varying not null
        constraint fk_status
            references status,
    created_on timestamp not null,
);

create table managers
(
    id bigserial constraint pk_managers primary key,
    role                varchar(50) not null,
    first_name          varchar(45) not null,
    last_name           varchar(45) not null,
    middle_name         varchar(45),
);
```

Comment: А нахрена подзапросы-то? Нужен один группирующий подзапрос во FROM, который считает количества для каждого менеджера, потом к результату JOIN собственно таблицы менеджеров, и нужный результат на экране.

Comment: @Akina А не подскажете примерно как это сделать? В SQL я слабо разбираюсь, к сожалению.

Comment: Выложите форматированным кодом: CREATE TABLE обеих таблиц (лишние для вопроса поля уберите), INSERT INTO с примером данных (2-3 менеджера, по 2-3 статуса на рыло), требуемый результат с пояснениями.

Comment: @Akina спасибо за помощь, подходящее решение указали ниже. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема в том, что подзапросы считающие количество ни как не связаны с внешним запросом и в итоге считают по полной таблице. Если использовать ваш подход с подзапросом, то надо добавить в него ссылку на менеджера во внешнем запросе и при этом requests в внешнем запросе вообще не нужен:

```
select concat(mn.last_name, ' ', mn.first_name, ' ', mn.middle_name) as fio,
       (select count(rq.status) from requests rq  where (rq.status = '103' or rq.status = '104')
           AND mn.id = rq.assignee) as assigned
  from managers mn on mn.role = 'oooz'
```

Но такое решение очень не эффективно, подзапрос выполняется заново для каждого менежджера, а в полном запросе еще и множество раз. Гораздо эффективнее считать количество сразу при group by, добавив условия подсчета (filter):

```
select concat(mn.last_name, ' ', mn.first_name, ' ', mn.middle_name) as fio,
       count(rq.status) filter(where rq.status = '103' or rq.status = '104') as assigned,
       count(rq.status) filter(where rq.status in('401', '501')) as routed_to_reg,
       ...
   from requests rq
   inner join managers mn on mn.role = 'oooz' and mn.id = rq.assignee
   where rq.created_on >= ?1 and rq.created_on <= ?2
   GROUP BY fio;
```

Внимание: данный запрос считает запросы только подпадающие под условие `rq.created_on >= ?1 and rq.created_on <= ?2` из вашего вопроса не ясно требуется именно такое поведение или нет.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь.)